# Moq, TDD and multiple layers

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, tdd, ninject, moq

I have a data assembly which defines my repositories.

I then have a service assembly which defines my services, each service has a repository injected into the constructor by Ninject.

When I'm unit testing my service methods, everything is fine:

```
[TestClass]
public class UserTests
{
    IQueryable<User> users;
    int userID;

    public UserTests()
    {
        users = new List<User>()
        {
            new User { EmailAddress = "known@user.com", Password = "password", ID = 1}
        }.AsQueryable();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Known_User_Can_Login()
    {
        // Arrange
        var repository = new Mock<IUserRepository>();
        var service = new UserService(repository.Object);

        repository.Setup(r => r.GetAll())
           .Returns(users);

        // Act
        bool loggedIn = service.UserLogin("known@user.com", "password", out userID);

        // Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(loggedIn);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, userID);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Unknown_User_Cannot_Login()
    {
        // Arrange
        var repository = new Mock<IUserRepository>();
        var service = new UserService(repository.Object);

        repository.Setup(r => r.GetAll())
            .Returns(users);

        // Act
        bool loggedIn = service.UserLogin("unknown@user.com", "password", out userID);

        //
        Assert.IsFalse(loggedIn);
    }
}
```

However, I'm running into problems when testing my controller (another level down).

My controller has dependencies on a service, and the service depends on a repository. I can't seem to get my controller tests to work. Here's what I have so far:

```
 [TestClass]
public class AccountTests
{
    IQueryable<User> users;

    public AccountTests()
    {
        users = new List<User>()
        {
            new User { CompanyId = 1, EmailAddress =  "known@user.com", Password = "password"},
            new User { CompanyId = 1, EmailAddress = "unknown@user.com", Password = "password"}
        }.AsQueryable();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Known_User_Can_Login()
    {
        int userID = 0;

        var repo = new Mock<IUserRepository>();

        // Arrange
        var service = new Mock<UserService>(repo.Object);
        var controller = new AccountController(service.Object);

        // Act
        var result = controller.Login(new LoginModel { EmailAddress = "known@user.com", Password = "password" }) as RedirectToRouteResult;

        // Assert
        service.Verify(x => x.UserLogin("known@user.com", "password", out userID), Times.Once());
        Assert.AreEqual("Index", result.RouteValues["Action"]);
    }
}
```

I keep getting an error about instantiating the UserService (i'm attempting to pass an instance of the UserRepository to it but it isn't working).

I must be doing something daft, but what?

Comment: I don't know moq/ninject but here is my take: since you are mocking your service it is never going to need a repository.  Your real implementation might.  You just need to test one level down.  You have your SUT and only need to mock the objects the the SUT is going to access.

Comment: @Paul I'd be interested in seeing the composition root that you use for your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that UserService is an interface.

Also, you must *not* create an instance of IUserRepository in your second test as you are doing here:

```
var repo = new Mock<IUserRepository>();
// Arrange
var service = new Mock<UserService>(repo.Object);
```

Since UserService is mocked, it will not make calls to IUserRepository anyway and you don't have to supply it's dependencies when creating the mock.

What you need to do is simply create the mock for UserService this way:

```
var service = new Mock<UserService>();
```

Even tough UserService normally has a dependency on a repository, Moq will just supply canned responses to methods and thus won't need to make the calls to the an actual repository.

Answer (score 1):

`UserService` class I am guessing is not an interface or an abstract class, if not then it is bound to fail since Mock cannot create an implementation of the `UserService`. Thus either create an interface for UserService or define it as an abstract class or instantiate it as follows:

var service = new UserService(repo.Object);

or you could use `Mock.Create<UserService>()` but you need to have provided all the implemenation UserService needs using `Mock.Provide<T>()` api.

Hope this helps.

If this isnt the problem please update the question with the classes for UserService and your repository